# cannot see files copied to usb drive from ubuntu to USB drive ini windows

Tags: usb

I have inserted my usb drive into my computer.  I have created a mount point "mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb.  I have copied files from cp home/my_name/folder/file_name to /media/usb.

I can see the files in ubuntu /media/usb, but I cannot see the files in the stick when I plug it in windows.  All I see is this folder is empty.

Apparently, I transferred my files from ubuntu to my usb drive but I cannot see then in the usb drive in windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to `umount /media/usb` before removing the stick.

Otherwise the changes to the filesystem might only reside in RAM (cache). USB drives are rather slow - it is highly likely that only some changes made it to the actual device. Try running `chkdsk` on the stick.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I run fsck I get fsck from util-linux 2.30.1. esfsck 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017) /dev/sdb2 is mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.  I mounted /deb/sdb1, not /dev/sdb2.  What does this mean? Thank you

Comment: I unmounted /dev/sdb2 and mounted /dev/sdb1 again (mount /dev/sdb1 /madia/usb) and when I run fsck Iget the following: Unable to resolve 'UUID=75799dc6-10ff-4108-9679-3b4eece87764.

Comment: fixed the last error. How do I interpret fsdk output?